# javascript load xml from document with ie9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, dom

what is the best way to change(without jquery) these html/javascript to work with ie9,

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="xmls">
            <xml id="myXml">
                <bookstore>
                    <book category="COOKING">
                        <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
                        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
                        <year>2005</year>
                        <price>30.00</price>
                    </book>
                </bookstore>
            </xml>
        </div>
        <!-- ...more html -->
    </body>
</html>
```

And read this html section with script

```
function readBooks() {
    var doc = null;
    try {
        doc = document.getElementById("myXml").XMLDocument.documentElement.childNodes.length;
        alert('msg =' + doc);
        //i need child nodes to iterate and show values,
    } catch (ex) {
        alert("problems to load xml" + doc);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

these works fine with ie6,7,8.

but with with ie9 not.

> the XMLDocument property is undefined,

thanks,

Comment: sorry, my xml is writed into html document

Comment: I think you forgot to mention what the concrete problem is. Have you tried it on IE9? Is it not working? How? Any error? Any unexpected outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following seemed fine in modern browsers

```
function readBooks() {
      var doc;
      try {
          doc = document.getElementById("myXml")
          alert('msg =' + doc.childNodes.length);
          for (var i = 0; i < doc.childNodes.length; i++) {
            if(doc.childNodes[i].tagName && doc.childNodes[i].tagName.toUpperCase() == "BOOKSTORE") {

                for (var j = 0; j < doc.childNodes[i].childNodes.length; j++) {
                    if (doc.childNodes[i].childNodes[j].tagName && doc.childNodes[i].childNodes[j].tagName.toUpperCase() == "BOOK") {
                        var book = doc.childNodes[i].childNodes[j];
                        alert(book.getAttribute("category"));
                        alert(getNodeValue(book.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]));
                        alert(getNodeValue(book.getElementsByTagName("author")[0]));
                        alert(getNodeValue(book.getElementsByTagName("year")[0]));
                        alert(getNodeValue(book.getElementsByTagName("price")[0]));
                    }
                }
            }
          }
      } catch (ex) {
          alert("problems to load xml" + doc);
          throw ex;
      }
  }

  function getNodeValue(node) {

      if (node.text)
          return node.text;
      return node.innerHTML;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

i solve these problem with
[String to XML, XML to String](http://www.hardcode.nl/subcategory_1/article_280-javascript-string-to-xml-object%3a.htm)